# How to change Spring Boot health actuator result for testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

When using Spring Boot *health* actuator
http://localhost:8080/health

```
{"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":122588196864,"free":59227926528,"threshold":10485760},"mongo":{"status":"UP","version":"3.2.6"}}
```

Now I want to check for other condition, so as to check dependent action are triggered when status is down. I want something like

```
{"status":"Down"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your custom '[Health Indicator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_writing_custom_healthindicators)' which would override the default Health Indicator and write your implementation (e.g. Always return status as `down`).

Now, as this is only needed to test the app, I would recommend annotating this with `@Profile` so that it only gets activated when the app is started with let's say `test` profile, e.g.:

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
```

By this way, if you start the app with any profile other than `test`, default `HealthIndicator` will be used.

Comment: thanks Darshan for the lead, can you tell what all cases the health goes down so that the scenarios can be recreated on a development machine.

Answer (score 0):

First disable the default **/health** endpoint or customize it to some different endpoint. You can disable it follow

```
endpoints.health.disabled=true
```

Once this is disabled, implement your own custom endpoints at **/health** and define your custom conditions with whatever you like to check.

You can take a look here for [creating custom endpoints](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-rest-endpoints-example#/customEndpoint)
Don't forget to use test profile while creating custom endpoint